# How can i get latest receipt from the list of latest_receipt_info?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have three type of subscription with 1 months, 6 months and 1 year. on the sandbox url `https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` i am getting a long list of receipt around **242** and its increasing with time.

I want to pass latest expiry date for the all subscription. how can i say that this is latest receipt for the perticular  subscription and pass expiry date for the subscripation to my web service

```
    {
    environment = Sandbox;
    "latest_receipt" = "MILFMwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoILFJDCCxSACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIK05AYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIK01QSCtNExgrTNMAoCAQgCAQEEAhYAMAoCARICAQEEAhYAMAoCARMCAQEEAgwAMAoCARQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAQECAQEEAwIBADA””;
    "latest_receipt_info" =     (
{
     "expires_date" = "2014-03-12 10:18:05 Etc/GMT";
                "expires_date_ms" = 1394619485000;
                "expires_date_pst" = "2014-03-12 03:18:05 America/Los_Angeles";
                "is_trial_period" = false;
                "original_purchase_date" = "2014-03-12 10:15:06 Etc/GMT";
                "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1394619306000;
                "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-03-12 03:15:06 America/Los_Angeles";
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000093384828;
                "product_id" = “myapp.1";
                "purchase_date" = "2014-03-25 12:21:23 Etc/GMT";
                "purchase_date_ms" = 1395750083000;
                "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-03-25 05:21:23 America/Los_Angeles";
                quantity = 1;
                "transaction_id" = 1000000104232856;
                "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000027948608;
}
  {
            "expires_date" = "2013-11-14 10:23:43 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1384424623000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2013-11-14 02:23:43 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_purchase_date" = "2013-11-14 10:20:44 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1384424444000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-11-14 02:20:44 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000093384828;
            "product_id" = "myapp.2";
            "purchase_date" = "2014-03-29 05:37:36 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1396071456569;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-03-28 22:37:36 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000093384828;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000027562376;
        },
  );
```

Comment: Please paste code how have you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: no still not. json data increasing with time not able to identifiy which is the latest receipt for the perticular subscripation.

Comment: The most recent one will have the highest value on the "transaction_id" property. Simply fetch that object? Would that work?

Comment: yaa it will but its possible to get the receipt for the particular subscription. in ios6 there is transactionReceipt will give the only for the particular subscription. but now appStoreReceiptURL giving lots of data with time. now before 1 hour it was 142 and now it was 780

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use kVC for that, something like this might work

```
NSDictionary *dictLatestReceiptsInfo = response[@"latest_receipt_info"];
long expirationDateMs = [dictLatestReceiptsInfo valueForKeyPath:@"@max.expires_date_ms"];
```

Comment: I suggest to use `valueForKeyPath:` instead of `valueForKey:` if there's an error : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: Yes that's actually what I wanted to suggest in the first place, thanks for pointing it out